# SQL Server collation -- closest to utf-8?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I can't seem to find a way to set the default collation of a database to `utf`(ish). For example:

[image]

For example, in mysql the default utf collation is called `utf8_general_ci`. Is there something similar for SQL server for this? Also, what does it use `Latin1` as default?

Comment: SQL Server supports UTF-8 as well; provided you are using the latest version. If you need UTF-8 support, you need to use SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @Larnu how do I see the version? I'm creating a "SQL Database" in azure: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.SQLDatabase.

Comment: Azure SQL Database and SQL Server in Azure both support UTF-8 collations. One example collation would be `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8`

Comment: @Larnu I see -- thank you. What is the whole "latin1" thing at the beginning for then?

Comment: Latin based characters. You know, the ones we're using *right now*. 

Comment: @Larnu where can I find the collation names available? The page it links to from the setup is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: If you connect to the `master` database, you can get a list available on the instance from the `sys.fn_helpcollations()` tvf.

Comment: @Larnu cool -- want to post an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8, you add "_UTF8" to the collation name to enable use of UTF8.  (SQL Server 2019 is required.) The example given is to change LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC to LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8.

If you will be migrating an existing database from a older version, I believe extra care is required to insure collation conversion is handled properly.  There can be side effects from the change in sorting.  Also, existing table definitions will use their original  collation.  This might be an issue if creating new tables that will use the new collation by default.